# Grease Pencil Fill On Surface Disappears At Distance

Tags: animation, grease-pencil

I’m using the Grease Pencil for the first time and the only issue that I have is that the fill color disappears when at a distance when I’m drawing on the surface of a mesh. However, I don’t get this problem if I hide the mesh I drew on.

The distance at which the fill disappears changes depending on the distance between the fill to the mesh behind it (demonstrated by the yellow plane).

This is problematic if I want to do any animations with this.

Any ideas?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/vATyf.jpg

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gv0L4.jpg

Comment: [How to upload an image to a post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491/how-to-upload-an-image-to-a-post)

Answer (score 1):

Grease pencil will only fill at "camera" or current "view" limits left to right and up or down. Else, the application will fill the 3d unlimited workspace forever catching it in a forever RAM eating loop. 
What you present in your videos, IS expected behavior to prevent the error I described above.